# Как переместить весь текст на ширину табуляции в vim?

Tags: vim

Допустим я написал код, после чего заметил, что забыл добавить условие в самое начало кода. Чтобы код был более читабелен я, конечно хочу переместить весь код ниже на ширину табуляции вправо от текущей позиции. Как это сделать сразу для всего (выделенного) кода?

Comment: нажмите `>` (знак «больше»)

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нажатие <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> в командном режиме сдвигает текущую строку вправо на величину, определённую в переменной `shiftwidth`.

если указать перед этим число, то оно определит *количество строк* (начиная с текущей), которые будут сдвинуты. т.е. <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> сдвинет текущую и следующую за ней строки.

---

нажатие <kbd>></kbd> в визуальном режиме (т.е. с выделенным блоком текста) сдвигает выделенные строки вправо на ту же величину (`shiftwidth`).

если указать перед этим число, то оно определит, *сколько раз* будет произведён сдвиг.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте команду `>>` в нормальном режиме или `>` в режие выделения.

Например, посчитайте, сколько строк вам надо сдвинуть, и введите это число, затем нажмите дважды <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. Или выделите этот текст нажмите <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, выделите текст, перемещая курсор, потом один раз нажмите <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущим ответам:

- Ещё стоит упомянуть <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> — автоматическое выравнивание.
- Если почему-то хочется других отступов, то можно выделить прямоугольный блок (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) и затем вставить пробелы вручную (<kbd>I</kbd><kbd>Пробел</kbd><kbd>Пробел</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

В копилку:

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>></kbd> - сдвинуть параграф на табуляцию, где *параграф* часть сплошного текста, отделенная пустыми строками сверху и снизу.

**Ссылки**

- https://www.zinkwazi.com/unix/notes/vimtips.html
- http://vimcasts.org/